# Audio not playing when added to homescreen - Sencha Touch

Tags: audio, extjs, ios7, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have an webapp made in sencha-touch that plays different audiofiles from URLs. It all works great, but when I add it to homescreen (on my iPhone 4s with IOS 7) everything but the audio is working...?

The way the audio is added is:

```
xtype: 'audio',
hidden: true,
url: '/audio/crash.mp3',
```

The correct audio-URL is added from store later.
I then have a button that finds the audio and sets:

```
audio.toggle()
```

Why is it not working when I add it to the homescreen? Is it a sencha or an ios7 problem?

Comment: You should have answered you own Question instead of commenting .

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip. Didn't know i could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem: It didn't work with the xtype: audio. I don't know why, but i think it is a bug in ios7 or something. The sollution or "quickfix" i did was to add an audio-tag with javascript and just play that.

```
var a = new Audio("YOUR AUDIO URL"); a.play();
```